# Is the "Akademischer Rat auf Zeit" (offered in Germany) equivalent to a postdoc or to an Assistant Professor?

Tags: postdocs, tenure-track, germany, assistant-professor

Once I asked about the exact *translation of a job title* offered at a German University, and related to a 6 year long position, generally called as "habilitationsstelle", the reply was something like this:

"For the first three years, the designation "scientific employee" is applicable (which is not further specified in a contract). Employment is in accordance with the collective bargaining agreement of the federal states (TV-L). According to this, a temporary appointment with the designation "Akademischer Rat auf Zeit" would theoretically be possible if all civil service law requirements were met."

Giving this brief context, that I hope is clear enough, what would the "Akademischer Rat auf Zeit" position correspond to?

Maybe to a postdoc, or to an Assistant Professor, or something else ?

Comment: Academic ranks and positions vary quite a bit between countries, and often there is no direct equivalence.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An "akademischer Rat" is not an assistant professor or a tenure track position. Those positions have actually "professor" in the name (actually, maybe even "tenure track"), and are paid according to the [TV-L W](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/beamte/by?id=beamte-bayern-2023&matrix=1) table.

An "akademischer Rat" can be a postdoc (maybe a long-term one preparing for his "habilitation"), but he can also be a doctoral candidate. The name "akademischer Rat" just indicates the type of contract with the state. ("Auf Zeit" just means "temporary", i.e., not permanent).

An akademischer Rat is an "official" ("Beamter"), which is a type of position that has more privileges than a standard employee of the state "öffentlicher Dienst". An "akademischer Rat auf Zeit" is paid according to the [TV-L A](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/beamte/by?id=beamte-bayern-2023&matrix=1) tables, and the extra privileges have to do with medical insurance and unemployment money.

A "wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter" is paid according to the [TV-L E](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l-2023&matrix=1) tables and is a normal employee of the state. Although it is more common to see postdocs in the "akademischer Rat" position, I have seen both doctoral candidates and postdocs being put in any of the two positions, depending on which one got free at the moment. In general, positions as "akademischer Rat" are becoming rare and in many places only "wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter" is available for both doctoral candidates and postdocs.

**Note:** the linked tables are valid only for the federal state of Bayern. If you are in another state, you have to check the tables for that state.

Comment: I would add that *assistant professors* do not exist as such in Germany and *akademischer Rat* is its closest equivalent, although there are many crucial differences.

Comment: @wimi, if Bayern includes Munich / Munchen, then we are on the right path

Comment: @Warcraft thanks a lot, so, the 
akademischer Rat might still be considered as a sort of Assistant Professor, or Junior Professor.. this is exactly what I am trying to understand, since, the acceptance of this offer would heavily depend on the "equivalent position". In other words, stepping back to a postdoc would be a firm "no", otherwise, if it is a sort of "professor-like" position it would be a "yes"

Comment: @limone To which extent the position is "professor-like" will depend on the specifics of the position, in particular, the amount of research and teaching, and whether you will be expected to develop your own research line vs. contribute to the research line of your boss.

Comment: Thanks @lighthouse keeper! Good to know :-) However, I was just thinking... In case it is an "akademischer Rat" (or a general "habilitationsstelle"), what can you write on an English CV..? I guess you cannot write the title "professor" event though it is a professor-like position... I mean, at the end of the day, the title is important for the next steps... Even though to the following employer you say "my duties and tasks are the same as of an assistant professor", being an "akademischer Rat", I think you can write "postdoc", or maximum "postdoc senior", but not some type of professor title..

Comment: @limone You can write something like "Akademischer Rat (position in the German academic system, comparable to assistant professor)" and then explain the specifics of the position. Of course, the specifics should then be of a kind that indeed makes it comparable to an assistant professorship.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot !!

Comment: "the extra privileges have to do with medical insurance and unemployment money" I would be surprised if somebody who becomes unemployed after previous work as an "Akademischer Rat" would get any unemployment money. The priviledge is more that you do not have to pay the monthly contribution to the system.

Comment: @Snijderfrey you get no unemployment money, but you get Übergangsgeld, which is some months of full salary after being dismissed or your appointment ending. Quite similar to unemployment money, in fact...

Comment: A postition as "Akademischer Rat", whether temporary ("auf Zeit") or permanent, requires a doctoral degree or equivalent, so is definitely a post-doc position. At least that is the case in Bavaria.

Comment: RIGHT, AS @Snijderfrey notes: You have to go to private health insurance and pay half yourself, the other half comes from the university. You also don't pay into the retirement fund or the unemployment insurance, so you are basically on welfare if you don't get a job right after. 
An no, do NOT use "assistant professor". It is absolutely not a professorship, but often a teaching job with a bit of research bolted on.

Comment: Strong disagree with @Wrzlprmft. An "akademischer Rat" is not close to an assistant professor position. You will not enjoy the privileges of professors in Germany, such as independently supervising PhD students, independent teaching, stronger voting power in committees, eligibility for certain grants, using the title "Prof.", pay scale "W" (instead of "A"), etc.

Comment: @MKR: Of course there are some differences to professors (just as there is between full and assistant professors elsewhere). Also, I didn’t claim that there is exact correspondence between assistant professors (which differ across countries anyway) and akademischer Rat. Going through your points: 1) If you have a habilitation, you can de facto independently supervise PhD students. 2) You can definitely teach your own courses (I am in a similar position and doing that). 3) Academic self-administration compares badly between countries anyway.

Comment: … 4) I am not sure about de-jure grant eligibility, but since de-facto eligibility strongly correlates with reputation which in turn strongly correlates with professorship. Also, I am would be surprised if there are no grants limited to full professors elsewhere. 5) The title is the minor difference we were starting from; no surprise here. 6) The payment scheme is truly minor. The actual pay is more interesting. But this one is not necessarily the same for full and assistant professors either. Also, there is some overlap between the A and W scales depending on experience.

Answer (score 3):

The position of "Akademischer Rat auf Zeit" in Germany is typically a temporary academic position that is equivalent to a postdoctoral researcher rather than an assistant professor. This position is often held by individuals who have completed their doctoral degrees and are gaining further research and teaching experience before pursuing a more permanent academic position.

In the German academic system, an assistant professor position is usually referred to as “Juniorprofessor” or “Wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter” with tenure track. These positions are more close to entry-level faculty positions and are generally considered higher in rank and responsibility than a postdoctoral or temporary position like “Akademischer Rat auf Zeit”.

Also, check specific details and requirements for each position as the terminologies and academic structures can vary between institutions understand its exact nature and responsibilities.

Comment: You need to check with the German state in which the university is located, as they make the rules.